# Vue binding data and $set

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using set function to change value of variable which controls a class. The variable changes successfully but class itself doesn't change.

Vue file:

```
<template>
    <li v-for="item in menu">
        <a href="" :class="{ 'show' : item.showNavItems }" 
                   @click="[$set(item, 'showNavItems', !item.showNavItems), toggleNavItems(item)]">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Prop, Emit, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({})
    export default class SideNavigation extends Vue {
        @Prop({ default: [] }) menu!: []

        toggleNavItems(item: any) {
            console.log(item);
        }

        created() {
            console.log(this.menu);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Menu variable is loaded from twig file like this:

```
<side-navigation v-bind:menu="{{ global_data.getSideMenu|json_encode}}"></side-navigation>
```

I can see that showNavItems variable changes after every click, but class 'show' doesn't change. I moved this code to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7c3wLvah/ and I can see that it's working, what is the problem with my real component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by defining another data variable, which becomes Vue.js object after the data is passed from Twig file.

```
@Prop({ default: () => {} }) menuData!: []
menu: [] = this.menuData
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't addes class name show in your style.
Also use square brackets for class binding like below this

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" :class="[item.showNavItems ? 'show' : ''] " @click="[$set(item, 'showNavItems', !item.showNavItems), toggleNavItems(item)]"><span class="holder"><i :class="item.holder"></i></span>{{ item.title }}</a>`

Comment: Yes I edited the fiddle, but the problem still persists. I can't seem to get it working on my component.

Answer (score 1):

the menu varible is an array not an object.
based on [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) you should use `$set` for array like `$set(arrayName, Index, newValue)`.
in your case that would be sth like this :

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in menu">
    <a 
      :class="{ 'd-none' : !item.showNavItems }" 
      @click="$set(menu, index, {showNavItems: !item.showNavItems ,title: item.title},)"
    >
   {{ item.title }}
   </a>
</li>
```

(i also change `.show` class to `.d-none` cause i thought it makes more sense :)) ).
you can test this solution on this  [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahmadreza_HK/zv6duhpr/)

Comment: Yes, fiddle works just as I need. But it's still not working on my application. Is it possible that my prop definition is wrong? @Prop({ default: [] }) menu!: []

Comment: @The50, Probably because the value you're pasing to `menu` prop is not reactive. Assign that value to a data property in parent component and then pass that property to prop.

Comment: Yes that's true. But what if I don't have a parent component? I solved this by adding a date property like: private menuFinal: [] = this.menu; but this doesn't look like a good solution, I would like to access this.menu instantly. I guess it's not how Vue works?

Comment: You can add `menu` to data and set default value to it : https://jsfiddle.net/d3gbLtkq/